# Error using dbscan from fpc package in R

Tags: r

I have searched around quite a bit and can't find anything that approaches an answer to my question.  I'm running the code below:

```
dbs <- dbscan(iris_tmp, 0.1, 38 )
calinhara(iris_tmp,dbs$cluster)
```

I'm getting an error that says:

```
Error in if (cln[i] < 2) cclx <- 0 : argument is of length zero
```

The if statement is within the calinhara function within fpc and it's working fine while I'm utilizing k-means so I'm at a loss as to why this would be happening.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: What does `dbs$cluster` say - every obervation is noise (`0`)? ` Do your values for eps and the min number of values per cluster make sense?

Comment: After looking at it more closely, I found that the calinhara function is throwing an error because dbscan is, I believe, saying that every observation is noise.

Comment: That's what I thought. If you adjust the parameters, you'll get clusters.